# ICO's and moving ETH

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, ico

Some Ethereum ICO's have you sign up, log in and give all the members a different ETH address to deposit to.

But with no equivalent bitcoin-cli 'move' function to internally move bitcoin within your own node for free then does that mean these ICO's have to pay gas just to move the ETH around in their own ETH node? Note: The bitcoin move function instantly moves the BTC around your own node for free.

-- side note: I do know some ICO's just have one address that uses the smart contract to automatically send out the tokens to the ETH wallet which sent the ETH.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if ICOs give everyone individual addresses, then they'll have to create on-chain transactions to get them all into one account. This is tremendously cheaper than Bitcoin though, since you can send ETH for less than half a penny. So if there are 100,000 contributors, all giving $10 each, the total to accumulate all $1 million can be as little as $500.